# Python Pickle Load Takes Longer Each Iteration

Tags: python, gzip, pickle

I have a gzip'd pickled file that is 4mb in size. Each time I open the file and load it the time it takes to unpickle takes longer. The contents of the file never change and the size stays the same.

Test Times:
1st Run: 27.5s
2nd Run: 44.1s
3rd Run: 52.7s

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
f = gzip.open( filepath, "rb" )
pickleFile = cPickle.Unpickler( f )
paData = pickleFile.load()
f.close()
```

Any idea why it is taking longer to load each time I run?

Comment: Are you loading it more than once into the same running Python process, or are you running a new process each time?

Comment: I'm assuming the same process as I don't have anything setup for multiprocessing.

Comment: I'm not referring to multiprocessing. What happens *between* test runs? Are you exiting the Python process, or are you loading your pickled file three times within the same Python process?

Comment: I'm not exiting the python process between runs.

Comment: Is this the full code? How are you doing your timing? Perhaps you're forgetting to subtract the initial value of "clock()" each time.

Comment: I only included the relevant parts, this is part of a bigger project that wouldn't make sense if I included everything.

It starts with firstTime = time.time(), the code runs, then I run secondTime = time.time(), and print "FILE LOAD TIME: ", (secondTime-firstTime)

Comment: @Niel: if your problem isn't replicated in the code that you posted (see Nix's answer) then it's a problem with the code you haven't posted. Perhaps you should try to generate a minimal test case.

Comment: I think Greg was on to something; what happens to the time if you exit your Python process and run this again? Does the time keep increasing from where it left off (I would be extremely surprised), or does it go back to ~27s and then start increasing?

Comment: As I mentioned below on Nix's answer, I've stripped it out of its original context now and it performs correctly consistently. Not sure though why the exact same test within the full context (Qt Application) would produce a different result. Possibly Qt is handling something differently each time... not sure... more digging required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created two test pickle file 3MBs and 22MBs, and zipped it.

I don't understand what you are doing because I just did a test and this code:

```
def get_time():
    return int(time.time())

while(count < 10):    
    filepath='/home/shared/word_out.gz'
    start = get_time()
    f = gzip.open( filepath, "rb" )
    pickleFile = cPickle.Unpickler( f )
    paData = pickleFile.load()
    f.close()
    end = get_time()

    print 'Time ellapsed' , end - start
    count+=1
```

Always prints out the same as I run it.

3 MB File:

```
Time ellapsed 1
Time ellapsed 1
Time ellapsed 0
Time ellapsed 1
Time ellapsed 1
Time ellapsed 0
Time ellapsed 1
Time ellapsed 1
Time ellapsed 0
Time ellapsed 1
```

---

22MB File:

```
Time ellapsed 5
Time ellapsed 4
Time ellapsed 2
Time ellapsed 2
Time ellapsed 3
Time ellapsed 2
Time ellapsed 3
Time ellapsed 2
Time ellapsed 2
Time ellapsed 2
```

Comment: Is pickle affected by the depth of the data it's loading in? My file is essentially a dictionary of dictionary's taking the form of:
paData = {'type':'anim', 'frames':{frame:nodeData}, 'image':'imgpath'} and nodeData = {'attr_name':(value,bool)} ... this comment is just in relation to differences in times.

Comment: Seems you're right Nix. I've stripped the code completely out of it's original context, run a test like yours and now I'm getting consistent times. Odd though that the same test within the full-context produces a different result... back to the drawing board.

Comment: What type of stuff is being done in the "full-context" code ?